# Vagrant provisioning script installs software (Pyenv) which requires shell restart

Tags: bash, vagrant, vagrantfile, pyenv, vagrant-provision

I am using Vagrant to spin up an Ubuntu box and run a shell script which configures the VM to use [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/). The Pyenv docs [recommend restarting the shell](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#restart-your-shell) after installation & configuration.

Having `exec "$SHELL"` in the middle of the script interrupts Vagrant's provisioning, so I opted to split the commands across two files.

*vagrantfile*:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "one.sh", privileged: false
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "two.sh", privileged: false


end
```

*one.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install PyEnv

curl https://pyenv.run | bash
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc


exec "$SHELL"
```

*two.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# install python build deps
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git

pyenv install 3.10

ten=$(pyenv latest 3.10)

pyenv global $ten

# Install Poetry 
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3.10 -
export PATH="/home/vagrant/.local/bin:$PATH"

# Install Nox
python3.10 -m pip install --user --upgrade nox
```

FWIW the vagrant command I run is:

`vagrant up --provider=hyperv`

When the second script attempts to execute the `pyenv` commands, its not found:

`default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 12: pyenv: command not found` 
However, I am then able to `vagrant ssh` into the VM where I can manually execute everything as I would expect.

```
vagrant ssh
vagrant@ubuntu-18:~$ pyenv --version
pyenv 2.3.9
```

I would expect the second provision script to '*pick up*' where the last one stopped, or at the very least not have a differently configured environment to when I subsequently `vagrant ssh` into the VM.

I have tried with each of the 'reset' and 'reboot' [options](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/provisioning/shell#options) set to true on the first provisioning script. result was the same.

Comment: The docs says the reason for the shell restart is to update PATH. You can avoid splitting this up by just specifying the full path to pyenv.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, that's solved the issue for me.